# Validating Upgrade of PHP applications

Tags: php

We have many php applications working on old php **version 5**.

Now am working on to update the codebase from **php 5 to php 8**. To update codebase am using packages like phpcompatibility/php-compatibility, phpcsstandards/phpcsutils etc.

After each application codebase update (to php 8) I will generate compatibility report (using phpcompatibility) to validate the update.

But I want to be sure (that codebase will work on php 8) and not only depend on report (phpcompatibility).

Hence, I **decided to deploy applications on local servers** (on php8, to check). **But each application** is giving me headaches. Each application **ask for specific requirements** (databases, users, files, classes). The php applciations were developed by other teams who have moved on (I dont have the environment in which they were developed).

Is there any **quick** way to do it? Am thinking may be I can -
1.go to production server
2.create docker Image
3. Open docker image locally and **update php** version(php 8)
4. Deploy php application in this local docker image (php applciation codebase is now 8)
5. If everything looks ok **then update the** production server version to php 8.

Am not sure will this work, is there any better way?